# When to use AVAudioPlayer method prepareToPlay()

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

If I instantiated an AVAudioPlayer object, set its properties, called prepareToPlay(), and called the play() method, but then change a property of my AVAuidioPlayer object do I need to call prepareToPlay() again?

Comment: i think you should call it!!!!

Comment: Do you change the property before the playback is finished?

Comment: @antonio, sorry thats a good question, the playback is on an infinite loop so the playback has not finished when I'm changing the property.  If it had stopped I know that I would have to call prepareToPlay() again.

Answer (score 2):

No you do not. This is from the discussion section in class reference for the method `play`:

> Calling this method implicitly calls the prepareToPlay method if the audio player is not already prepared to play.

Additionally, this is the abstract for that method:

> Plays a sound asynchronously.

When we look at the properties of `AVAudioPlayer`, we can see that non of them have an explicit attribute about atomicity, which makes them `atomic` by default. While the playback is asynchronous, your playback will not be affected from the property modifications (while the asynchronous operation will put a lock on those properties). Plus, this method calls `prepareToPlay` implicitly, even if you do not do this yourself.